# How to get authorization header correctly when using Get Blob from azure storage service?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage, azure-automation

I used Authorization Bearer in my header to storage service by using resource of https://storage.azure.com.

This is how I make my header.

```
$Body2 = @{
    resource = "https://storage.azure.com/"
    client_id = $clientid
    grant_type = "client_credentials"
    client_secret = $password
}
$token2=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.windows.net/$TenantId/oauth2/token" -Method 'POST' -Body $Body2 -Headers @{"accept"="application/json"} -UseBasicParsing
```

The above command gives me an access token which I put in my header like below.

```
Name                          Value                                                                                    
----                           -----                                                                                    
Authorization                  Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x-ms-version                   2017-11-09                                                                               
x-ms-date                      Fri, 10 Aug 2018 13:27:34 GMT
```

And I used this command,

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myfile.txt" -Method 'GET' -Header $Header -UseBasicParsing
```

The problem is that it's come up with an error of `Invoke-RestMethod : AuthorizationFailureThis request is not authorized to perform this operation.` which is weird because we already grant a permission of service principal to download from blob storage.

Is my header using Bearer is the wrong way? What's wrong with using it and how to fix this issue?

Comment: You should post all of your powershell code. What is actually in $Header?

Comment: What would be more relevant is posting how you got the bearer token.  I also suggest adding `-Verbose` to your `irm` call since you will get a gigantic dump of helpful info

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid already updated my question please take a look.

Comment: @NoRefundsNoReturns Thanks for your suggestion. I will try.

Comment: Why your Uri is `https://myaccount.blob.com/mycontainer/myfile.txt`. It seems that it is not a blob storage uri like `https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myfile.txt`.

Comment: Ah yes it's that URI. I think I misspell in my question. Actually I used that link and it's still reject me @JoeyCai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is my header using Bearer is the wrong way?

As I have test, the header with the token you generate is right.

> What's wrong with using it and how to fix this issue?

According to the error message you provided, it seems that `403 forbidden` error. And you have grant permission to app to download blob, then you need to add app registered to your storage account to give permission. You could refer to the following steps to achieve it.

1.Grant permission to App registered in Azure AD.
[image]
2.In Storage Account click `Access control(IAM)` and add permission to the App.
[image]
3.The working output.
[image]

Comment: Your answer should work but sadly I don't have enough permission to do this and we change the method from using storage account to local instead.